# Quick question concerning the derivative of a power series

Tags: calculus, analysis

If we take $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}$

wolframalpha gives the derivative of the function as $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n}}{n!} = e^{-x^2}$ however, we had a theorem in class stating if a power series can be differentiated we'd get the derivative starting from n = 1, not n = 0:

so $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n}}{n!}$ would be the derivative at first thought, but I can see this is wrong - but how am I applying the theorem incorrectly? Is it because the first term of $f$ is not constant?

Comment: It is because the powers of $x$ are not $0,1,2,...$ but $1,3,5,...$

Comment: I assume the theorem you are talking about said something like, the derivative of $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$ is $a_1+2a_2x+\cdots$. Does this start with 0, or with 1? Well, the subscripts on the coefficients start with 1, but the exponents on $x$ start with 0. Is that at the root of your question?

Answer (score 1):

This power series contains only terms of odd powers, and hence its derivative contains terms of even powers only, and since the power series starts from the first power of $x$, then its derivative start with the zero power of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem you cite is correct for when the exponent of the variable is just $n$. Here obviously we have $2n+1$.